# apex action function on anchor tag

Tags: visualforce, controller

so here i am trying to pass the value of param to controller on click of `<a>` href tag.I am using `<actionSupport>` for that to send the value to controller with onclick event.But no value is being passed to controller.If that is not possible any alternate solutions to pass value using anchor tag.

Any suggestions

```
<a href="https://c.ap5.visual.force.com/apex/AgreementRegistrationPage" ><div class="fab">ENROLL</div>
        <apex:actionSupport action="{!GetName}" reRender="" event="onclick">
        <apex:param value="Health Insurance" name="PolicyName"/>
        </apex:actionSupport>
        </a>

Controller

Public class HealthInsurance {
    Public String PolicyName{get;set;}
    Public PageReference GetName(){
        system.debug('inside method');
     PolicyName=ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('PolicyName');   
      system.debug(PolicyName);  
        return null;
    }

}
```

Comment: Yes with help of apex:outputLink

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try with this

**Vf Page** :

```
   <apex:page controller="HealthInsurance" >
    <apex:form>
        <apex:commandLink value="ENROLL"  action="{!GetName}">
        <apex:param  name="PolicyName" value="Health Insurance"/>
        </apex:commandLink >     
    </apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

**controller**

```
public class HealthInsurance{
 Public String PolicyName{get;set;}

    Public PageReference GetName(){
        system.debug('inside method');
        PolicyName=ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('PolicyName');   
        system.debug('******** PolicyName' + PolicyName);  
        PageReference pg=new PageReference('https://c.ap5.visual.force.com/apex/AgreementRegistrationPage');
        return pg;
    }    
}
```

Comment: Is it not possible through `<a>` tag..And also through outputlink its not working Nitesh

Comment: Your page also get redirect ?

Comment: Yes it is redirecting but value is not populating

Comment: @DeepakAgarwal Updated answer for you

Comment: @DeepakAgarwal Your welcome......

Answer (score 1):

The `<apex:actionsupport>` tag only works inside Visualforce tags, not directly on standard HTML tags.  As shown in another answer, you can use [`<apex:commandLink>`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_compref_commandLink.htm) to create a link that directly calls a controller method, without needing `actionsupport`.  You can use [`<apex:outputlink>`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_compref_outputLink.htm) in VF to create an `<a>` in the rendered HTML that links to an URL (as opposed to an action).

You can also use [`<apex:actionfunction>`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_compref_actionFunction.htm) to create a javascript function that invokes a controller method, and call that JS function from anywhere that you would normally call a JS function in a page.